# Display Taxonomy Terms in an option tag with value being the slug

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms, slug, categories

I have a custom taxonomy filled with terms that I wish to display in a fashion such as below.

```
<option value="[SLUG]">[TERM]</option>
<option value="[SLUG]">[TERM]</option>
<option value="[SLUG]">[TERM]</option>
...
```

I have attempted to use "wp_dropdown_categories" but I was unable to find a way to change the value="[TERM_ID]" to value="[SLUG]"

I also tried to use "wp_list_categories" and have it display with out the li's hoping there was a tag like "wp_nav_menu" has with 'before'=>'','after'=>'' but the documentation for "wp_list_categories" doesn't seem to support that.

If you have any ideas on how to accomplish this it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`get_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) and output the term objects within whatever markup you need:

```
$terms = get_terms( 'your-taxonomy' );

if ( $terms ){

    echo '<select>';

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo '<option value="' . $term->slug . '">' . $term->name . '</option>';
    }

    echo '</select>';

}
```

Comment: this is perfect.